# React-Native Firebase list refresh

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

I'm pretty new to React Native, redux etc so I'm hoping you can help. Essentially I have a 'timeline' and I want this to listen to any updates on firebase. If there is a new post it will add the new post.

In my home component I call the below action:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.listFetched();
}
```

In my action I get the snapshot and 'reverse' order it and send 'feed' to my reducer.

```
export const listFetched = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
    const feed = [];
    firebase.database().ref('/posts').orderByChild('timestamp').on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach((listSnap) => {
            const list = listSnap.val()
            feed.push(list);
        });
        console.log("END FEED: " + JSON.stringify(feed));
        dispatch({ type: LIST_FETCHED, payload: feed });
    });
};
};
```

This returns the list which I pass through. If I refresh the device it displays everything as expected, but when I add something new I need to refresh manually again for it to display.

```
renderItem({ item }) {
    return <ListItem listItem={item} />
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.list}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    );

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const list = _.map(state.list, (val, uid) => {
    return { ...val, uid };
  });
    return { list };
};
```

For some reason if I use the below action instead it automatically refreshes the list without me manually doing it.

```
export const listFetched = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.database().ref('/posts').orderByChild('timestamp')
            .on('value', snapshot => {
                dispatch({ type: LIST_FETCHED, payload: snapshot.val() });
            })
    };
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be more worried about the first one not updating automatically since you're using "on" and not "once" in your firebase fetch, if anything, the second action is doing its job right, you call it once and then the "on" will update whenever the firebase updates automatically. if you want to be in control of when it updates, with "once" instead of "on".